# problem is that the code print the letters twice

Tags: java, string, file, for-loop

i'm writing a code that read from a file then print the frequency of each alphabetic letter

that is my code

```
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Text.txt"));
    BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Output.text"));

     String str = "";
     str = read.readLine();
     str = str.toUpperCase();
    
    while ((str = read.readLine()) != null) {
        int[] count = new int[26];
        str = str.toUpperCase();
         
        for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) >= 'A'  && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                count[str.charAt(i) - 'A']++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
            if (count[i] >= 0) {
                write.write("The frequency of letter " + (char) ('a' + i) + " = " + count[i]);
                write.newLine();
            }
        }
        
    }
```

but the problem is that the code print the letters twice even i convert the letters to uppercase.
how can i fix this problem?

thank you so much guys

Comment: Can you show your output file? Have you tried setting breakpoints in the code? Also, you need to close the output writer.

Comment: Start by locating _where_ it's printing it twice. Reduce that print statement until it _only_ prints the wrong thing. Which variable(s) are involved? Then trace up: which lines of code handle those variables? What are they doing? Also, note that your first string read gets discarded: you declare `str`, read a line of text into it, make it uppercase, and then you immediately overwrite that because of `while ((str = read.readLine()) != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file has two lines, then the frequencies will be printed "twice" because your file writer is inside the for-each-line loop.

If you're trying to print the character frequencies for the entire file, then try this

```
try (BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Text.txt"));
    BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Output.text"))) {
    // counts for file
    int[] count = new int[26];

    // read whole file
    String str;
    while ((str = read.readLine()) != null) {
        str = str.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) >= 'A'  && str.charAt(i) <= 'Z') {
                count[str.charAt(i) - 'A']++;
            }
        }
    }
    // loop counts and write frequencies to output file
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] >= 0) {
            write.write("The frequency of letter " + (char) ('a' + i) + " = " + count[i]);
            write.newLine();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For large files, you may want a `long[] count`

Comment: that works amazing , you solve my problem . thank you.